# Bootstrap row not aligned to left of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a staging app to look at: https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/request

Right below the navbar, there's a row that contains the Start Rental & End Rental input fields. Those input fields should be centered across the entire page. Right now they're too far to the right, because in looking at an inspect element, the row somehow starts more to the right, but without any margin or padding interference (see the white space to the left in the screenshot below). The container immediately wrapping the row is fine. Thanks!

[image]

EDIT

[image]

WITHOUT WIDTH:100%

[image]

Comment: You've got over 1k rep, surely you know you're gonna get downvoted for not sharing code?

Comment: Didn't know that honestly... thanks for enlightening me, will do so in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the containing div change the class container to class container-fluid.

You will want your html to be structured something like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    </div>
  </div
</div>
```

The outter most DIV can have a class of container or container-fluid.  Container will have margins on the left and right side of the page, container-fluid will not.  Next you will specify that you want a row (row by default is 12 columns wide in bootstrap, assuming you didn't change this).  And then the last div should specify how many columns you want that div to take up.

Comment: That worked, though admittedly I'm still not sure why... I've read the docs and know the difference, but in my case, I don't get why I needed a container-fluid and not container... if you have a moment, can you explain a little more in detail?

Comment: When you set the class to "container" on a div, that will add a margin-left:15px and margin-right:15px to that div.  This can be seen in your browsers developer console by inspecting the html element.  the container-fluid class on the other hand does not add margin-right and margin-left css to the div, therefore it will stretch the entire width of the browser window. Let me know if that clarifies things.

Comment: So I knew that, but I guess what I'm confused by is why in the inspect element in my screenshot, the row highlighted is totally blue and shifted right; what i mean is, there is no orange margin that I can see, so that threw me off, because I didn't know what to adjust for. also it's weird because on the rest of my pages i don't need `container-fluid` (my understanding is to use this only if content needs to touch the edge) for similar content (i.e., not touching the edge) and it works fine....

Comment: You didn't see the orange margin because in your picture you are inspecting the row, not the div that holds the row.  If you inspect the div element with class="container non-navbar" you will see the margins on both sides of the page highlighted orange.  The element inspector won't ever show margins for parent elements. In terms of formatting for other elements, I would need some exact examples to explain what is happening.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I ddi the best job explaining. I attached another screenshot that shows the inspect element on the next row. See the difference in how this second row has the blue that doesn't show margin but is not pushed out to the right? That's what I'm not understanding... why was one row shifted and required container fluid, while the second is fine?

Comment: That first div had an id="date-row" while the second div had an id="non-date-row".  The id="date-row" was overriding the normal bootstrap behavior and setting a custom width of 100% for that element.

Comment: ah well... this is totally what happens when you make hacky solutions. I even have a comment in my CSS stating I don't know why the `width:100%` is needed, but if it doesn't.. well.. see image, now the row is like impossibly small. I guess I'm not fully understanding how all the pieces fit. It SEEMS like there is a solution to create my desired design (which you've done btw) without `container-fluid` or the `width:100%` on the `date-row`, and somehow I've missed that solution entirely. I'm not super proficient at Bootstrap so if you'd care to comment holistically I'd love it

Comment: Everything you are trying to do can be done with the bootstrap scaffolding.  I would remove any custom css and just review this documentation.  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Yeah... that's what I tried to do initially. In the last screenshot, there's no special CSS, but alas, you get the weird effect, that forced me to put width:100% into date-row, which, I guess somehow forced me to make the container fluid. Oh well...